# Kaminari, pagination, AJAX strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I managed to get my AJAX page load working, but I run into something I don't know how to fix: I set number of entries per page to be 4. On first page it loads 4 items alright but on the next page, it loads more than 4 items. Why's that?

live site: https://serene-waters-1174.herokuapp.com/

I checked the logs and I realised the `OFFSET` is not staying consistent after each ajax load. ON page load `OFFSET` is for, like I want, on subsequent loads, the `OFFSET` is `0`.

```
Started GET "/users/index?page=2" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 21:17:29 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 4
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (0.3ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  Rendered users/index.js.erb (35.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 42.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/users/index" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 21:17:34 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as JS
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (0.9ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  Rendered users/index.js.erb (48.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 57.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      paginates_per 4
end
```

#### user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.order(:name).page params[:page]

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js {}
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

#### index.html.erb

```
<h1>All users in database.</h1>

<div id="paginator">
    <%= paginate @users, :remote => true %>
</div><br>

<div id="list">
    <%= render 'user' %>
</div>
```

#### index.js.erb

```
$('#list').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@users) %>');
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@users, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

I will appreciate some help with getting my "next" links to load page with ajax.

EDIT: 
I realised from the page source that no all pages only 4 items are being shown. Perfect. But in the view, it shows 4 items, and repeats those same items 4 times.

EDIT:

This fixes it in the partial. I was previously using a `.each` loop on the partial.

```
<%= "Name: #{user.name}" %> <br>
<%= "Email: #{user.email}" %><br>
<%= "Album: #{user.album}" %>
<p>======</p>
```

Thanks to [smathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152786/smathy)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OFFSET` is governed by the `params[:page]` - and as you can see in your logs the `:page` parameter is not being sent through on the second request.

However, none of that would explain why more than 4 users are being shown on a page, both SQL queries show the correct `LIMIT 4` so perhaps you have another error in your JS for updating the DOM or maybe in your user partial and it's adding the users instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was leaving the partial as is with the `.each` loop but changing my js.erb file to render the partial instead of the instance variable.

```
$('#certs').html('<%= escape_javascript render "certifications/certification" %>');
```